# Data Validation drop down list stopped showing arrow for drop down

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

To start off, I used VBA to create this drop down list.

```
With Range("C17").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:="3, 4, 5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9, 10 ,11, 14, 18"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = "Reinforcement number."
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

At the beginning, it worked just fine. When I select the cell, the flipped triangle will pop at the right of the cell and when I click it, the drop down list will appear. Now, for some reasons, after the cell is selected, nothing shows up, neither flipped triangle nor the drop down list. This happened to the whole worksheet, even those I created manually(without VBA). Another problem that happened earlier, but somehow it fixed itself, is that when I typed in one of those value in the list for ex: 6, it gave me the error like I input some number not included in the list.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A shot in the dark... `With Range("C17").Validation` I see you have not fully qualified the range. In such a case, it will create the validation in the "Activesheet". Is it possible that the active sheet which you think is active may not be active? Try something like `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C17").Validation`

Comment: Thank you very much! Although, this workbook only has 1 worksheet.

Comment: @yoohooo's Still will be an issue if 2 workbooks are open at the same time. A code can also run on another workbook if thats the active one. If you want to be safe never use unqualified `Range` objects (same for any other objects in a workbook like `Rows`, `Columns`, `Cells`,  …).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. How are you calling the code? Can you copy it to a standalone proc in a module say `Sub Sample()` and run it from there? Does it work then?